# How to set constant in Karma Unit Tests

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I've this piece of code in Angular 1. And test cases written in Karma. Here I've covered all the lines.
But the "if" condition is lowering the branch coverage. Somehow I have to test it with "falsy" condition.

Not getting how to pass the "after" constant as undefined.

```
$scope.$on('klresource-bag.drop-model', (event, el, container) => {
    const changedIndex = domIndexOf(el[0], container);
    const changed = $scope.resources[changedIndex];
    const after = $scope.resources[changedIndex - 1];
    let afterId = 0;

    if (!isUndefined(after)) {
        afterId = after.model_resource.id;
    }

    $scope.$save(() => {
        const s = KLResource.sort({
        id: changed.model_resource.id,
        after: afterId,
        }, {});

        return s.$promise;
    });
});
```

Here is my Unit test case.

```
describe('klresource-bag', () => {
    it('Checks the event "klresource-bag.drop-model"', () => {
        scope.$save = () => {};

        spyOn(Array.prototype.indexOf, 'call').and.returnValue(1);
        spyOn(scope, '$save').and.callFake(func => func());
        spyOn(KLResource, 'sort').and.returnValue({ $promise: {} });

        scope.$broadcast('klresource-bag.drop-model', {}, [{}], {});

        scope.$apply();

        expect(Array.prototype.indexOf.call).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(scope.$save).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Function));
        expect(KLResource.sort).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Object), jasmine.any(Object));
    });
});
```

I tried setting this in my Unit Test but it is throwing errors :

```
scope.resources = undefined;
```

Comment: why the path is `scope.ui.resources`, as of what I see, you should place mock data into `scope.resources`

Comment: Ahh, my bad. Forgot to update there. Now updated the question.

Comment: well now, can you show us the part where you did put something into `scope.resources` variable?